# Why do I have this Flutter error in Firebase (I am a newbie)?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing noSQL databases for a student project but when I make a query through Firebase I get an authentication error.
**Error**
[image: FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)]
**Main Code (main)**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Part of the code with the error**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsers();
  }

  void getUsers() async {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

    QuerySnapshot users = await collectionReference.get();

    if (users.docs.length != 0) {
      for (var doc in users.docs) {
        print(doc.data());
      }
    }
  }
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
... ...
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.1.0
```

I already tried changing the rules in Firebase and nothing

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow get, update, create,read, write, delete: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://firebase.google.com/ then open your project and follow these steps:

1. Open Firestore Database
2. up you have tabs select second tab which called rules
3. then allow write and read by writing the code below inside match function

> allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 3);